# How to show distance between residues in Pymol

Tags: python, pymol

With the [**this PDB file**](http://www.filedropper.com/pdp4gg6cd1i) and the following [PyMOL](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Main_Page) code:

```
cd /Users/foo/Desktop/
reinitialize
load pdp_4gg6CD1_I.pdb
as cartoon 
select chainI, chain I
select chainC, chain C 
select chainD, chain D 
show sticks, chainI
spectrum count, cyan_red, chainI
color yellow, chain C
```

I can make this image:

[image]

What I want to do is to show the distance between the selected residues in chainC (yellow)
with chainI (stick).

The selected residues of  chainC that I want is this:

```
[9, 23, 25, 44, 53, 54, 55, 59, 62, 63, 66]

Y    Y   H   W  R   R   F    F   T  N    V
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to get the closest distance between one atom in your selection from chain C and another atom from chain I? Getting the distance of all atoms your selection to all atoms in chain I is easier but but the answer is quite messy.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters: Closest one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Let's use `cmd.iterate` to get all the atoms in a selection (chain C and chain I) and write the coordinates and atom name to dictionaries for later use.
- Then we can calculate all the distances between all atoms and write the closest residues and atom names to two lists (`min_c` and `min_i`)
- In the last step we only have to draw the distance objects between the closest atoms and we are done :)

---

```
from math import sqrt

def closestAtoms(list1=[9, 23, 25, 44, 53, 54, 55, 59, 62, 63, 66], list2=[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]):
    atoms = {}
    atoms2 = {}

    for r in list1:
        command = "chain C and resi %s" % (r)
        coordinates = {'atoms': []}
        cmd.iterate_state(-1, command, 'atoms.append([x, y, z, name])', space=coordinates)
        atoms[r] = coordinates['atoms']

    for i in list2:
        command = "chain I and resi %s" % (i)
        coordinates = {'atoms': []}
        cmd.iterate_state(-1, command, 'atoms.append([x, y, z, name])', space=coordinates)
        atoms2[i] = coordinates['atoms']

    for i in list2:
        min_dist = 10**3
        for c in list1:
            for cc in atoms[c]:
                for ii in atoms2[i]:
                    dist = sqrt((cc[0] - ii[0])**2 + (cc[1] - ii[1])**2 + (cc[2] - ii[2])**2)
                    if dist < min_dist:
                        min_dist = dist
                        min_c = [c, cc[3]]
                        min_i = [i, ii[3]]
        cmd.distance('dist_%s_%s' % (min_c[0], min_i[0]), 'chain C and resi %s and name %s' % (min_c[0], min_c[1]), 'chain I and resi %s and name %s' % (min_i[0], min_i[1]))

cmd.extend("closestAtoms", closestAtoms)
```